# SQL use previous records values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data as follows before update. I am trying to get an end result that looks like the "After Update" image. of the highlighted cells

1 - I need to fill the end date column of each of the previous row with the start date of the following row. I am using SQL Server 2008 with no lag and lead functionality.

2 - Also need to fill the current GOLD row as follows

```
CarryoverFrom = the ID of the previous not immediate PREMIUM row
CarryoverFrom2 = the ID of the immediate previous PREMIUM row 
CarryoverAppliedTo = Sum of the Carryover amount of the previous PREMIUM rows
```

** Note that each GOLD row deals only with the previous PREMIUM rows that happened after a GOLD row. For example ID 5 row deals only with PREMIUM row ID 4 and not the PREMIUM rows in ID 2 and 2

**--BEFORE UPDATE**
[image]

**--AFTER UPDATE**
[image]

Comment: Without `LAG, LEAD`, self-join is one of the options. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `LAG` or `LEAD`, you can self-join the table by row number. So for item 1 it would be:

```
UPDATE A SET [End Date] = NextRecords.[Start Date] FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Start Date]) rownum FROM [table]) A
INNER JOIN (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Start Date]) rownum FROM [table]) NextRecords 
ON A.rownum + 1 = NextRecords.rownum
```

Item 2 will be similar, but a bit more elaborate.